# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: ///// problemas con free

Tags: c

Tengo esta pieza de código, nada especial, es para probar la reserva dinámica de memoria. tengo un error cuando pongo `free(p)`, obtengo una lista de errores que no comprendo (los pongo abajo) si quito free no tengo ningún problema. no entiendo a que puede deberse, se debe liberar memoria con free después de usar un `malloc`, y esa es mi duda, el por qué del error. (pego el código debajo del la salida de error)

La salida por consola me da lo siguiente:

> *** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff32dd2f55 ***
>       ======= Backtrace: =========
>       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bfb)[0x7f941847abfb]
>       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76fc6)[0x7f9418480fc6]
>       ./a.out(+0x80a)[0x560fb2c2f80a]
>       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f941842a2e1]
>       ./a.out(+0x67a)[0x560fb2c2f67a]
>       ======= Memory map: ========
>       560fb2c2f000-560fb2c30000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1179741                    /home/inav/Documentos/42madrid/punteros/a.out
>       560fb2e2f000-560fb2e30000 r--p 00000000 08:21 1179741                    /home/inav/Documentos/42madrid/punteros/a.out
>       560fb2e30000-560fb2e31000 rw-p 00001000 08:21 1179741                    /home/inav/Documentos/42madrid/punteros/a.out
>       560fb47fc000-560fb481d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
>       7f94181f3000-7f9418209000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 11668349                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>       7f9418209000-7f9418408000 ---p 00016000 08:21 11668349                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>       7f9418408000-7f9418409000 r--p 00015000 08:21 11668349                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>       7f9418409000-7f941840a000 rw-p 00016000 08:21 11668349                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>       7f941840a000-7f941859f000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 11668316                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
>       7f941859f000-7f941879f000 ---p 00195000 08:21 11668316                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
>       7f941879f000-7f94187a3000 r--p 00195000 08:21 11668316                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
>       7f94187a3000-7f94187a5000 rw-p 00199000 08:21 11668316                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
>       7f94187a5000-7f94187a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>       7f94187a9000-7f94187cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 11668292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
>       7f94189b0000-7f94189b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>       7f94189cb000-7f94189cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>       7f94189cc000-7f94189cd000 r--p 00023000 08:21 11668292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
>       7f94189cd000-7f94189ce000 rw-p 00024000 08:21 11668292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
>       7f94189ce000-7f94189cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>       7fff32db4000-7fff32dd5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
>       7fff32dd7000-7fff32dda000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
>       7fff32dda000-7fff32ddc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c[] = "hola mundo";
    char* p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);

    printf("%s\n", c);
    printf("%p\n", &c);
    p = c;
    printf("%s\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", &p);
    free(p);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No puedes liberar con `free` memoria que no has pedido con `malloc`. Vamos a ilustrarlo con ASCII art:

```
char c[] = "hola mundo";
char* p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);
```

```
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
c --> [h|o|l|a| |m|u|n|d|o|0]

       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
p --> [?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?]
```

El puntero `c` apunta a una zona de memoria de tamaño estático (definido en tiempo de compilación) que contiene once caracteres con valores 104, 111, 108, 97, 32, 109, 117, 110, 100, 111 y 0.

El puntero `p` apunta a una zona de memoria solicitada en tiempo de ejecución mediante `malloc` (`m`emory `alloc`ation) que tiene espacio para once caracteres y sus valores son desconocidos.

Tanto `c` como `p` tienen valores diferentes (apuntan a sitios diferentes) en el momento en que igualas `p` a `c` ambos punteros pasan a apuntar al mismo sitio: la zona de memoria de tamaño estático (definida en tiempo de compilación).

Cuando posteriormente intentas liberar con `free` el puntero `p`, dicho puntero ya no apunta a la memoria solicitada en tiempo de ejecución con `malloc` (el sitio original) si no a la memoria definida en tiempo de compilación (**sin `malloc`**):

```
         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
c --+-> [h|o|l|a| |m|u|n|d|o|0]
    |
    |    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
p --/   [?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?|?]
```

La memoria solicitada dinámicamente ahora es inaccesible, e intentas liberar con `free` una memoria que no pediste con `malloc`, lo que provoca el error que ves, encabezado por una llamada a `munmap_chunk()` quejándose de un puntero no válido

> ```
> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
> ```

Las funciones [`mmap` y `munmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap) (`m`emory `map`: mapeo de memoria y `m`emory `unmap`: desmapeo de memoria) son funciones de bajo nivel que manejan la memoria. Al intentar liberar como memoria dinámica memoria que no fue solicitada dinámicamente estas funciones fallan.

---

Probablemente lo que querías hacer era esto:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c[] = "hola mundo";
    char* p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);

    printf("%s\n", c);
    printf("%p\n", &c);
    memcpy(p, c, sizeof(c)); // Copiar 'c' en 'p'
    printf("%s\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", &p);
    free(p);
    return (0);
}
```

Con `memcpy` (`mem`ory `c`o`py`, copia de memoria) estás copiando la memoria apuntada por `c` en la memoria apuntada por `p` sin hacer que ninguno de los dos punteros deje de apuntar donde apuntaba.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que te pasa es que haces el `malloc` y luego pierdes la referencia a esa zona de memoria cuando igualas la dirección de `c` a `p`:

```
p = c;
```

`c` es constante porque lo defines apuntando a la dirección de memoria donde está guardada la cadena `"hola mundo"`.

Por otro lado a `p` le asignas memoria con `malloc`, reservando un espacio. Pero luego al hacer `p = c`, haces que `p` apunte a `"hola mundo"` y no a la memoria reservada con el `malloc`. Con lo que cuando intentas hacer `free( p)`, está intentando liberar la memoria de `"hola mundo"` y no la que reservaste con `malloc`.

Si lo que pretendías al hacer `p = c` era copiar el contenido de `"hola mundo"` a la zona de memoria reservada con `malloc`, así lo único que estás haciendo es igualar las direcciones de memoria y no el contenido. Para copiar el contenido tendrías que usar funciones de cadena (`strcpy`, por ejemplo).

Un saludo.